# Создать класс, экземпляры которого можно передавать в функцию в качестве Delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, делегаты

Мне нужно объявить класс `MyLambda`, экземпляры которых представляют собой различные лямбда-функции для фильтрования значений. Как сделать, чтобы экземпляры этого класса можно было передать в качестве аргумента в функцию:

```
MyList.Where(myLambdaInstance);
```

Решая эту задачу, я столкнулся с проблемой, что унаследовать пользовательский класс ни от класса `MulticastDelegate`, ни от класса `Delegate` невозможно, выходит [эта ошибка компилятора](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0644). Существует ли какой-то базовый класс, наследники которых можно будет передавать в функции в качестве `Func` или `Delegate`?

Comment: Дайте больше информации, чего именно хотите добиться в итоге. / Метод `Where` - это стандартный линковский метод? Или ваш собственный?

Comment: `Func<int, bool> lambda = x => x % 2 == 0;` - так, например, можно создавать экземпляры лямбд. Далее их можно использовать в вызовах методов: `.Where(lambda)`. Этого достаточно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, `System.Linq`. Боюсь что объявить `Func<int, bool>` и использовать не получится. У меня в приложении - макросы, они пишутся на специальном разрабатываемом мной языке. И вот я хочу объявлять эти скриптовые лямбды (это уже реализовано), и эти лямбды передавать в качестве аргумента в `Where`, `Select` и другие методы, требующие "вызываемый объект" при помощи `Invoke` из библиотеки `System.Reflection`